# Problem with camera access on firefox mobile

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

In my web app for mobiles, I want to show mobile camera using Firefox mobile browser, i'm using nodejs with express as a server and i'm connecting to server via localhost with my smartphone. Firefox browser ask for camera access, i'm not getting any error but still didn't see camera output. When i'm testing it on chrome desktop everything's work fine.

There's some code:

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documentl</title>
        <base href="/">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="main.css" >
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <div class="booth">
            <video id= "video" autoplay></video>
        </div>

        <!--<script src = "script.js"></script>-->
        <script>
            (function(){
                var video = document.getElementById("video"),
                    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                navigator.getMedia =    navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                        navigator.msGetUserMedia;

                navigator.getMedia({
                    video: {exact: "environment",
                            width: 1280,
                            height: 720 },

                    audio: false
                }, function(stream) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = stream;
                    video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, function(err){
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
                });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
    const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendfile('index.html'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I didn't use chrome mobile becouse of "only secure origins are allowed here"

versions:

nodejs - v8.10.0
express - 4.16.4
mobile Firefox - 63.0.2
desktop chrome - 69.0.3497.100

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem? If something is unclear, please ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

For recent browsers, you need to set `srcObject` for MediaStreams.  The object URL doesn't work anymore.  Try this:

```
video.srcObject = stream;
```

You should have the same problem in Chrome as well... if not, you will in an update soon.

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem, after changing the code the camera does not display on the chrome desktop version.

Comment: @SalimAzeri Neat.  What versions of everything are you using?  Any errors in the JavaScript console on Chrome Desktop?  Also, you're not using any WebRTC polyfills by chance, are you?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, i updated question with versions. About polyfills: nope, i'm using only code which i posted. In chrome browser i'm getting: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." due video.play() method, and: "[Deprecation] URL.createObjectURL with media streams is deprecated and will be removed in M71, around December 2018. Please use HTMLMediaElement.srcObject instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5618491470118912 for more details." due video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);

Comment: @SalimAzeri Like I said in my answer, you need to use `srcObject` instead.  Remove the code for `createObjectURL()`.  As for the first error, that's pretty clear.  You need to allow the user to click/tap something before you playback a video on mobile.

Comment: @Bard, thanks for help, working with video.srcObject = stream; i just typed sth wrong.